# Struggling to get count of an item from secound table in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am struggling to get info from my secound table (Cars), which contains items of cars in the category table. With the category, I can use this to count how many cars there is in the category.

This code below is working great to get count of an item from category from cars.

```
     public PartialViewResult GetCars()
    {
        var view = db.Cars.GroupBy(s => s.Category.Name)
            .Select(x => new CarsCountViewModel
            {
                Name = x.Key,
                Counts = x.Count()
            }).ToList();

        return PartialView("_ChooseJobsPartialViewLayout", view);

    }
```

And this code below, I want to join the code above into this. Also See the comment in the code.

```
public PartialViewResult ChooseCity()
    {     

        var view = db.City.GroupBy(s => s.Name)
              .Select(x => new CityViewModel
          {
              Name = x.Key,
              Counts = x.OrderBy(d => d.???).Count(), <-- How can I get items from the Category table that I want to count? 

          });

          return PartialView("_ChooseJobsPartialViewLayout", view.ToList());

 }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.ViewModels.City.CityViewModel>


<div class="container">
    <div class="well">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">



                <div class="form-group">
                    <h4>?</h4>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <label>@item.Name (<strong>@item.Counts)</strong></label>
                            @Html.RadioButton(item.Name,
                            item.CityId,
                            new
                            {
                                id = "radio",
                                type = "checkbox"

                            })

                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

POCO models:

```
public class Cars
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

   public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
   public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public int FilePathId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
   public string UserId { get; set; }
  public virtual User Users { get; set; }



}


public class Category
{
    private ICollection<Cars> cars;
    public Category()
    {
        this.cars = new HashSet<Cars>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cars> Cars
    {
        get { return this.cars; }
        set { this.cars = value; }
    }

}

  public class City
{   
    [Key]
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: How is Car and City related? Can you show us the class diagrams?

Comment: Hi @ManishKumar and thanks for your answer. Please see my POCO models.

Comment: Cars and Cities aren't related according to your POCOs.....